# How to data-bind with Razor and Knockout

Tags: razor, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm trying to set a Knockout-bound function's parameter with Razor. I've tried...

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { return myFunc(@Type.SomeType.ToString()); }">
    Click Me
</a>
```

and..

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { return myFunc(@Html.Raw(Type.SomeType.ToString())); }">
    Click Me
</a>
```

and..

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { return myFunc('@Html.Raw(Type.SomeType.ToString())'); }">
    Click Me
</a>
```

and..

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { return myFunc('@(Html.Raw(Type.SomeType.ToString()))'); }">
    Click Me
</a>
```

Is there a right way to do this?

(Background: this is for use in a bootstrap dropdown)

Comment: The 3rd snippet should work. What is the error?

Comment: Unterminated string constant on each apostrophe. It's not connecting the two apostrophes. Same error if I swap the apostrophes and quotes.

Comment: Have you tried `myFunc('@(Html.Raw(Type.SomeType.ToString()))')`?

Comment: That gives the same error

Comment: Try to extract the value to a variable before appending it (`var val = Html.Raw(Type.SomeType.ToString())` then `return myFunc('@val');`.

Comment: I think it is really ugly to use Razor to render a script, but up to you

Comment: Please include a little more information, including the MVC/Razor version, what `Type.SomeType` is, the result / error for each of your attempts, and the expected rendered outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to surround `data-bind` attribute with single quotes (`'`) and pass the parameter using `Json.Encode`.

Full example:

```
@{
    // A string with a lot of special characters
    string myStr = "abc\"\\/'#{}@.:xyz";
}

<span data-bind='click: function() { myFunc(@Json.Encode(myStr)); }'>
    Click Me
</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<script>
    ko.applyBindings({
        myFunc: function (myParam) {
            console.log(myParam);
        }
    });
</script>
```

In your case it would be:

```
<a href="#" data-bind='click: function() { return myFunc(@Json.Encode(Type.SomeType.ToString())); }'>
    Click Me
</a>
```